# `showexpl` doesn't work with accents

Tags: accents, showexpl

It seems that `showexpl` removes the accents when it is processing them.

How can I make it to use accented letters?

Is there a replacement or a similar package that is more robust?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset {
  literate=%
    {á}{{\'{a}}}1
    {é}{{\'{e}}}1
    {í}{{\'{i}}}1
    {ó}{{\'{o}}}1
    {ú}{{\'{u}}}1
    {ñ}{{\~{n}}}1
    {Ñ}{{\~{N}}}1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  á é í ó ú a e i o u
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{LTXexample}
  á é í ó ú a e i o u
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `showexpl` uses the `listings` package, this is a duplicate of [Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24528).

Comment: @AlanMunn: not really. The accents disappear also in an ansinew encoded files. Also the example shows that in lstlisting itself the accents works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer reading too fast I guess. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 5):

showexpl has to write the code to a temporary file. It uses an internal command of listings for this. But accent doesn't survive if you use the `literate` option too. Put the code in some external file and then use

```
\LTXinputExample{test-code}
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that breaks the idea of using `showexpl`. As I wanted to keep the code I'm showing within the same file, and without duplicity. In that case, I may just copy paste the code, but that solution is not maintainable.

Comment: Well you can use an enviroment like filcontents* from the filecontents package or VerbatimOut from fancyvrb to output the code on-the-fly. In many (but not all) cases this should work fine. If your file is utf8 encoded: check carefully the encoding of the output file. Writing utf8 is a bit tricky. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47462/inputenc-error-with-unicode-chars-and-verbatim. You could also make a feature request for showexpl.

Answer (score 3):

Run `xelatex` and everything will be fine without using the `literate` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.88]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
áéíóúaeiou
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{LTXexample}
áéíóúaeiou
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: `showexpl` automatically loads `listings`.